# Получение Range с помощью Sheets API на python

Tags: python, google-spreadsheet, google-sheets-api

В общем, законнектил к питону google sheets api и пытаюсь считать данные из таблицы

`worksheet.cell().value/worksheet.acell().value` работают прекрасно и возвращают значение одной ячейки, но мне не подходит данный способ, так как есть огран на 60 операций в минуту, а данных у меня много.

Пытался найти что-то вроде `.getRange("A1:X").getValues()` в `AppsScript`, но в API Питона никак такое найти не могу. Нашел `worksheet.range()`, но он возвращает массив с `Cell ID (<Cell R3C5 '02.01.2022'>)`, а мне нужно просто значение `(02.01.2022)`. `worksheet.range().value/values` не работает, уже всё перерыл. Ребят помогите кто шарит, буду очень признателен

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Здесь не смотрели? Хотя не знаю, оно ли https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values#python

Answer (score 1):

Нашел. Если кому-то нужно будет:

```
worksheet.get_values('P6:P80')
```

`.range()` устарела